# Adjust the screen brightness depending on the time

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I'm looking for a solution/script to adjust brightness (like this http://jeff.ecchi.ca/blog/2010/11/28/ajustement-de-la-luminosite-de-lecran-en-fonction-de-lheure-sous-gnome/ but for KDE ).

I don't want to change temperature of color (like redshift or F.lux), only the brightness.